# Why isn't my PHP cURL working on SendGrid?

Tags: php, curl, sendgrid

I'm trying to integrate API with my website. I have tried three different API keys. I always get an error:

"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked"

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
         
   $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send';
   $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer          {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}'
   );                                                                                        
   
   $email = array
   (
      'to'        => "myemail@server.com",
      'toname'    => "Example User",
      'from'      => "sendingemail@otherserver.com",
      'fromname'  => "Your Name",
      'subject'   => "PHP Test",
      'text'      => "I'm text!",
      'html'      => "<strong>I'm HTML!</strong>",
  );
         
   $curl = curl_init($url);

   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($email));
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            
   $response = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   $result = json_decode(preg_replace('/^'.pack('H*','EFBBBF').'/', '', $response), true);
   var_dump($result);

?>
```

Comment: try removing space after bearer

Comment: Is the bearer token really inside `{}`?

Comment: SendGrid has an API library, why don't you use that instead of `curl`? https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

Comment: The curly brackets were the issue. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the results from the comments here:

The issue was caused by the braces surrounding the actual token.

However, it's also worth calling [SendGrid has an API library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#send-an-email-to-a-single-recipient) that can be used instead of cURL.